# Symmetric product

Tags: vector-bundles

Let $E$ be a vector bundle of rank $r$ and degree $d$ over a smooth curve $X$. Is there any canonical exact sequence for $Sym^k(E)$? in particular what is the degree of $Sym^k(E)$?

Suppose $E$ is stable, is $Sym^k(E)$ is stable ? 
Is there any interesting information about $Sym^k(E)$?

Thanks

Comment: For calculations of degree, one uses `splitting principle'. Pretend that $E=L_1\oplus \cdots \oplus L_r$, direct sum of line bundles. If $e_i=\deg L_i$ (which we do not know), $Sym^k(E)$ is easy to write down and thus its degree in terms of $e_i$. Finally, use $d=e_1+e_2+\cdots +e_r$ to get rid of the $e_i$. For example, taking $r=k=2$, we get $\deg Sym^2(E)=2e_1+(e_1+e_2)+2e_2=3d$. Hope this helps.

Comment: $Sym^k(E)$ is semi-stable, and is stable for very general $E$. This is a consequence of a famous theorem of Narasimhan-Seshadri. You can find a proof of your question in Hartshorne's ASAV.